# php a href link don't work

Tags: php, href

How to make it properly? The variable is not working in href link

```
<?php
$currentlang = get_bloginfo('language');
$pl = "http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/CV.pdf";
$en = "http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/Curriculum-Vitae-English.pdf";
?>
<?php if ($currentlang=='pl-PL') { ?>
<a href=$pl class="vecard" title="<?php _e( 'CV', 'site5framework' ); ?>">CV</a>
<?php } else { ?>
 <a href=$en class="vecard" title="<?php _e( 'CV', 'site5framework' ); ?>">CV</a>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: you missed <?php tag in href before $pl ...! should be <a href="<?php echo $pl; ?>" class="......

Answer (score 2):

**Correct Your code,**

```
<?php
$currentlang = get_bloginfo('language');
$pl = "http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/CV.pdf";
$en = "http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/Curriculum-Vitae-English.pdf";
?>
<?php if ($currentlang=='pl-PL') { ?>
<a href="<?php echo $pl; ?>" class="vecard" title="<?php _e( 'CV', 'site5framework' ); ?>">CV</a>
<?php } else { ?>
 <a href="<?php echo $en; ?>" class="vecard" title="<?php _e( 'CV', 'site5framework' ); ?>">CV</a>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: It should be <?php echo $en;?> for second time!

Comment: You're missing quotes.

Comment: yup, but @Codelover edit code after my answer...there was $pl before by the way..

Answer (score 1):

Do this:

```
<?php
$currentlang = get_bloginfo('language');
$pl = "http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/CV.pdf";
$en = "http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/Curriculum-Vitae-English.pdf";
?>
<?php if ($currentlang=='pl-PL') { ?>
<a href='<?php echo $pl; ?>' class="vecard" title="<?php _e( 'CV', 'site5framework' ); ?>">CV</a>
<?php } else { ?>
 <a href='<?php echo $en;?>' class="vecard" title="<?php _e( 'CV', 'site5framework' ); ?>">CV</a>
<?php } ?>
```

Add quotation marks and add `<?php` tag in the variable.

Comment: It should be <?php echo $en;?> for second time!

Answer (score 1):

You are not calling your variable the proper way. Use this:

```
<a href="<?php echo $pl; ?>" .... > text </a>
```

You need to call it inside  and use echo for it, including quotations marks to wrap the `href` with.

Comment: Look at some of the other answers. You're missing quotes. `<a href="page.php">LINK</a>` as an example.

Comment: It's not proper HTML. Look at the HTML source.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php if ($currentlang=='pl-PL') { ?>
<a href="<?php _e( $pl, 'site5framework' ); ?>" class="vecard" title="<?php _e( 'CV', 'site5framework' ); ?>">CV</a>
<?php } else { ?>
 <a href="<?php _e( $en, 'site5framework' ); ?>" class="vecard" title="<?php _e( 'CV', 'site5framework' ); ?>">CV</a>
<?php } ?>
```

According to your coding standards!!